# How do I reset the django cache for static file names?

Tags: django, caching, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have a problem with a django 1.4 site hosted on Heroku. We are using Memcache for various caching, like template and static asset caches. [Update: According to django docs, django does not seem to use memcache for template loader caches]

Sometimes when I push the site to heroku, the links to the static css files don't update until the cache clears (either manually or I'm guessing when it times out as it seems to fix itself after a few minutes if I leave it alone).

So this is unacceptable since my HTML is the new version, and my css would be the old version until the cache updates and the url changes to the new css file.

Example:

The site has html (we'll call this v1) and that links to a css file like:
application.5e6e7ad87005.css

I make changes to the application.css file and push the site. This causes a new css file name to be generated by the staticfiles stuff, lets say:
application.5e6e7ad87006.css

The problem is that on my html page, they still all link to the old file (application.5e6e7ad87005.css).

I'd like to clear the cache of ONLY the cached filenames (at least, I'm assuming this is what the problem is, if someone thinks this is a different problem, please let me know) so as not to lose my other caches (template caches, query caches, etc.)

From searching, it seems that I can only clear ALL the cache at once, not individual caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all really depends on what caching strategy you're using for your templates. Are you caching the entirety of each template and rendered page?

If so, then I suggest using [template-fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) instead. The idea is that you would only cache certain parts of each template that are really expensive to render. You would not cache the parts that are supposedly fast to render, for example the links to your css files.

I suggest you also look into [django-compressor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_compressor), which does an awesome job both at minifying CSS/JS files on the fly and at making sure that the latest version of those files systematically gets used (provided you're not caching the links to those files, of course).

Comment: I have the default template caches enabled, but we are not explicitly caching anything:

`(                                                                
  ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (                         
      'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyFilesystemLoader',               
      'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyAppDirectoriesLoader',           
      'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',                    
      'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',               
      ),),                                                                
)`

Comment: I suppose that means that our entire templates are cached for whatever the default setting is (I think we have the timeout set to "500", which is how the heroku add-on said to set it up.

Comment: Would doing template fragment caching be a better alternative to the 'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader' template loader, or is that not related?

Comment: Going to mark this as the best answer since the template cache seems to be the issue- I'll look into clearing that out when I push, though I wish django would do that automatically when my staticfiles change.

Comment: Using 'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader' is a nice performance improvement, however as you've seen it can be a little tricky to refresh things. One thing to note though, is that those templates are *not* cached in the caching engine (i.e. in your case, Memcached), but in the Django process' memory. This means that to refresh your templates, you actually need to reload the Python code in memory, either by restarting your Web server (say, Apache if that's what you're using), or simply doing 'touch <your-wsgi-file>'.

Comment: Hmm, sometimes a restart doesn't fix it (using heroku, so I just 'heroku restart', but a cache clear always fixes it. I did notice that when I add new items to the site, the pages updates instantly, so maybe this isn't a cache issue? Or maybe django is somehow smart enough to clear the template cache when writing to the db and this happens automatically? (seems fishy to me, like the cached filenames are something else)

Comment: Do you know of any resources that explain exactly what the django.template.loaders.cached.Loader does? I had assumed it caches the compiled templates until they change, but perhaps it's caching the output of the template? Now that I've thought about it more, that seems unlikely, since I have user-specific content on every page, and surely it isn't caching every single page for every user.

Comment: Some more specific q's (maybe I should open a new stackoverflow question?) 1) Where does django store the filenames for the staticfiles after you run collectstatic? And when is that cleared? I would have assumed it was cleared whenever you run collectstatic, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Normally the cached loader should not interfere with Memcached. It just stores the compiled templates that are on disk into the process' memory. It does not store the rendered pages. You can find more info in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Comment: that's what I thought it would do - so then why would the paths to my static files not be updating when I deploy and there are new files? Running collectstatic should update the urls, and it doesn't seem like template caching is the problem, but rather how the url to the static files is stored.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd say that `heroku config:add ...` is your friend.

For example: you can create a bash script that pushes your latest app for you and, on doing so, fires, say: `heroku config:add GIT_LAST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)`.

Then in your Python code you can reference that variable by using `os.environ['GIT_LAST_COMMIT']`.

For example here's my Heroku app: http://stormy-badlands-7331.herokuapp.com/

The code for `app.py` is:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
  return 'Hello World! The latest commit sha is %s' % os.environ['GIT_LAST_COMMIT']

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
  port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

And my `deploy.sh` is:

```
git push heroku master
heroku config:add GIT_LAST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Note that I update the variable after I push, this way I ensure that users don't get served the old assets under a new hash.

You can then take this `os.environ['GIT_LAST_COMMIT']` and use it as the `x` var, for example, when loading your assets, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css?{{ git_last_commit}}" />
```

Comment: Hmm, well I don't like this method for a couple of reasons: 1) Using a query string won't work well for some proxy servers, better to use actual filenames. 2) This will rev every file every time I push, not just the files that change. Django's staticfiles app already does a really good job of generating new filenames whenever the file changes.

The issue I'm having is simply with the updating of the html that links to the files when I push - it seems that my template cache is just too aggressive.